# What is the cost to DROP DATABASE in Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Google Cloud SQL has a price for I/O operations.

What is the cost of a DROP DATABASE operation? E.g., is it a function of the size of the database, or a fixed cost?

Similar questions for DROP TABLE as well as deleting an entire instance.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud SQL currently uses innodb_file_per_table=OFF so all the data is stored in the system table space. When a large database is dropped all the InnoDB pages associated will be put in the list of free pages. This will only require updating the InnoDB pages that hold the bitmap table for the free pages so the number of I/O operations should be small. A just did a test and dropping a database 60GiB+ took about 18 seconds.

Dropping and table or an instance incur the same cost.

Deleting an instance doesn't cost anything. :-)

Note that, due to the use of innodb_file_per_table=OFF the size of the database will not decrease.